# What is best approach to AngularJS data service pattern?

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-promise

I have big application with many controllers. I inject `PaymentService` to those controllers, to have single point of data source. The `PaymentService` get data by asking remote server using angular `$http` service.

Controllers can ask `PaymentService` for data in random order and in random point of time. I want following functionality:

1. the 1st controller that asks for data gets an unresolved promise
2. any next controller that asks for data gets either:
   2.1 yet pending unresolved promise from p.1
   2.2 or... resolved promise with cached data (if promise has resolved already)

The tricky part is that another controllers can update data in my `PaymentService`, so if I cache just promise, the data in already resolved promise are not updated.

I have found examples of caching data or caching promises, but:

1. **caching promise pattern** - is missing solution for problem of another controller updating already fetched and cached data inside resolved promise
2. **caching data pattern** - has flaw, when 2nd controller requests data before data is cached, the 2nd promise and 2nd data request is created.

The solution I figured out https://jsfiddle.net/kj3mwpvr/2/ (focus on `getBalance()`) seems too complicated, and I want to ask for best (or simpler pattern) for such scenario?

Comment: check this out [link](http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/)

Comment: Yuza - solution under your link has the same flaw I described. "getBook: function(bookId) {...}" will create multiple calls and promises if we call it 2nd time before it is resolved for the 1st time